# learning intval

Tags: php

can you tell me what is the function of `intval`?
and what about this?

```
'.intval($_POST['bla']).'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an easy way to prevent SQL injections. If your query is like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM salads WHERE id = " . $_POST['salad_id'];
```

Then if the user passes the string "id" in instead of an actual id, then all your salads will be deleted!!

But if you wrap [intval()](http://php.net/intval) around it, it'll convert any bad dressings to the integer zero, and no salads will be affected.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM salads WHERE id = " . intval($_POST['salad_id']);
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just read [the manual article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)?

> intval — Get the integer value of a variable

This table from that page gives a great example:

```
echo intval(42);                      // 42
echo intval(4.2);                     // 4
echo intval('42');                    // 42
echo intval('+42');                   // 42
echo intval('-42');                   // -42
echo intval(042);                     // 34
echo intval('042');                   // 42
echo intval(1e10);                    // 1410065408
echo intval('1e10');                  // 1
echo intval(0x1A);                    // 26
echo intval(42000000);                // 42000000
echo intval(420000000000000000000);   // 0
echo intval('420000000000000000000'); // 2147483647
echo intval(42, 8);                   // 42
echo intval('42', 8);                 // 34
echo intval(array());                 // 0
echo intval(array('foo', 'bar'));     // 1
```

Comment: lol - you're acting like that's the first result if you google 'intval' </sarcasm>

Comment: I think answers from people are more "user-friendly" then manuals

Comment: @ggfan have you read the php manuals? They are answers from people and they have major discussion threads about every possible nuance.